# want to show the transparent to navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, popup

Transparent view is not working for full screen. i have one screen with navigation bar. And when i show pop up for that screen. i use to show the transparent at back side.

But now its working only from below navigation bar to till screen end. And not applying for navigation  bar.

But i want to show the transparent to navigation bar too. How to do that,

here mu uiview code that make a transparent :

```
  trasnView =  UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        trasnView.backgroundColor =  UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.9)


        self.view.addSubview(trasnView)
```

I dont know why for my navigation bar alone its not applying.

Thanks in advance !!

UPDATE :

I did manually adding uiview. but when i apply in view controller. i have navigation controller too for that view controller. So that view is working only below the navigation bar ....not above the navigation bar

Comment: please, share much more code than this, share working case e not working one, and in both case post images, you need to clarify your question otherwise nobody will answer

Answer (score 0):

Solution is below:

```
trasnView =  UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.windows[0].frame)
trasnView.backgroundColor =  UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
self.view.addSubview(trasnView)
```

Comment: no i am getting same. navigation bar dont have the blur

Comment: I did manually adding uiview. but when i apply in view controller. i have navigation controller too for that view controller. So that view is working only below the navigation bar ....not above the navigation bar